# java.security.NoSuchProviderException: SunEC error

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am trying to write an ECDSA java algorithm to implement in android phones. The data is parsed using NFC. That's what the `write(id+"?"+nama+"?"+signature+"?"+saldo, mytag)` is for.

Here is what I wrote:

```
       String id = null;
       String nama = null;
       String saldo = "50000";  

       if(edNIM.getText()!=null && edNama.getText()!=null){
                  id = edNIM.getText().toString();
          nama = edNama.getText().toString();
       }
        String C = id+"?"+nama+"?"+saldo;
        String signature = ECKeyGen.Generate(C);

        write (id+"?"+nama+"?"+signature+"?"+saldo, mytag);                 

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Writing to Tag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Writing to Tag" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

While the `ECKeyGen.Generate(C)` is

```
public static String Generate(String x) throws Exception{
    KeyPairGenerator kpg;
    kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC","SunEC");
    ECGenParameterSpec ecsp;
    ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp192r1");
    kpg.initialize(ecsp);

    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privKey = kp.getPrivate();

    Signature ecdsa;
    ecdsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA","SunEC");
    ecdsa.initSign(privKey);
    byte[] baText = x.getBytes("UTF-8");

    ecdsa.update(baText);
    byte[] baSignature = ecdsa.sign();
    String signature = (new BigInteger(1,baSignature).toString(16)).toUpperCase();
    return signature;
}
```

The problem is, when I debug the program, it keeps skipping the code from `String signature = ECKeyGen.Generate(C)` to `catch(Exception)`.

The log says `java.security.NoSuchProviderException: SunEC`.

What does this mean?

Can someone explain to me where my mistake is?

Comment: Well what is the exception? Please show the full stack trace including the exception type and message. You should *always* include that if you're asking a question about an error.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet I got the code to generate the signature from "Implementing ECC with Java Standard Edition 7" paper by Martinez and Encinas. In the paper, he wrote that exact code. I didn't quite get why he used the `throws Exception`, but if I removed the `throws Exception` syntax, the `kpg=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance()` gets an error. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to include the details of the exception. Something is failing, but at the moment you've given us *no indication* what that is. You have the information - it's in the log. Please include it in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for the inconvenience, here is what the log says `java.security.NoSuchProviderException: SunEC`. What does this mean?

Comment: As I said before, please edit this into your question, and give the full stack trace. But hey, it sounds like there's no "SunEC" provider registered... that's what you should look into. (A search for "SunEC" would be a good starting point.)

Comment: @JonSkeet This is easy enough to answer for me, even without the exception, but now the exception is in the title it should be reopened.

Comment: Meh, this is never going to get reopened. `"SunEC"` is a provider containging an implementation and not part of the official API. That provider is Sun/Oracle specific and certainly not available on Android. Try [SpongyCastle](http://nelenkov.blogspot.nl/2011/12/using-ecdh-on-android.html) instead, and don't specify providers *unless you really need to*.

Comment: @owlstead I've changed `SunEC` to `SC` and imported the jar files. The thing is, I've been trying to run this code to my android phone. The data and signature is parsed using NFC into an NFC tag. Now the error changes to `java.io.IOException` `at android.nfc.tech.Ndef.writeNdefMessage`. But when I tested the application (without ECDSA) the `NdefMessage` seems to be working fine

Comment: Try the functionality separately. That could well be a timing issue or something similar. It seems unrelated to the issue itself - logically anyway. There is no need to specify "SC" unless you require *provider specific functionality*. Otherwise the JCA implementation will (basically) look for a registered provider that implements the "EC" and "SHA1withECDSA" algoririthms for the specific services (`KeyPairGenerator` and `Signature`).

Comment: @RedCrimson - please post your answer as an answer rather than as an edit to your question, then you can come back later and accept it.

Comment: I've figured out what went wrong. Owlstead is correct, SunEC is not compatible with android, so I changed the provider to bouncycastle, and the program works fine. The `java.io.IOException` error is because the NFC Tag can only store data with limited size.  
So, when I changed the `write(id+"?"+nama+"?"+signature+"?"+saldo,mytag)` to only `write(signature)`, the program works perfectly fine.  
But there's another problem, what do I do to verify the signature generated by a different program? @owlstead

Comment: @RedCrimson Eh, that last question is too general for me. You use a trusted public key that is part of the key pair containing the private key that signed it, then use the `Signature` class to verify. That's as much as I can say without more details. If you get stuck, don't hesitate to post another question (after searching for Q/A of the same here, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"SunEC"` is a provider containing an implementation and not part of the official API. That provider is Sun/Oracle specific and certainly not available on Android. Try SpongyCastle instead, and don't specify providers unless you really need to.

Comment: OK, this is a repost of my comment, as I was wrong on one point; the question did get re-opened.